# Cannot create project in Eclim

Tags: java, eclipse, vim, eclim

Hello good people of Stack Overflow, I have come with yet another question for your bountiful knowledge to answer. I am having a problem using eclim, a program that integrates the features of eclipse for java development into the Vim editor.

I am unable to create a project using the syntax defined on [eclim.org](http://eclim.org), which is this vim command, ":ProjectCreate /path/to/dir -n java". I am typing this like this, ":ProjectCreate /home/username/Java -n java", where username is my username. The error I get is,

```
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Java does not exist]
while executing command (port: 9091): -command project_create -f "/home/username/Java" -n java
```

This led me to test if Java was installed on my system, using java -version. The output is,

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.1) (6b22-1.10.1-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

So I had Java installed, and I believe that is the OpenJDK version that is not used in my eclim installation. The version I specified is Java 1.6.0_24 of the sun Java JDK. That's beside the point though, as I do have Java installed.

So that's what led me to you. One last thing I would like to add though. I am using a headless server to run the eclim server in the background. This is through Xvfb, and is also detailed on [eclim.org](http://eclim.org). I don't believe that is causing the problem, but I just thought it would be handy to throw in. As always, thanks for the help that will doubtless be provided.

Comment: Probably you need JDK along with JRE. What does it say when you type javac ?

Comment: I figured it out, I am not able to name it Java as the vim command line(ex I think?) interprets Java as another command to tack onto ProjectCreate. However, I am not able to answer my own question for another 8 hours as I do not have enough Karma. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done further testing and my original comment was not the correct reason. The real problem, was that I already had a directory at ~/Java. That tried to execute that directory for the project, which it could not do.